# Ruby : Extract Key and Value from hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have an array of hashes that I'm having trouble with extracting the `key` and `value`. The array looks like:

```
data = [{"key"=>"Name", "value"=>"Jason"}, {"key"=>"Age", "value"=>"21"},
        {"key"=>"last_name", "value"=>"bourne"}]
```

How can I convert this to the following array of hashes?

```
[{"Name"=>"Jason"}, {"Age"=>"21"}, {"last_name"=>"bourne"}]
```

I was able to use `detect` :

```
a = d.detect { |x| x["key"] == "Name" }
puts a['value']
```

to get the value for `"name"`, but would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: `data` is an array, not a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the most elegant way to go about this is probably to convert `data` into a Hash first (assuming there are never any duplicate keys), like so:

```rb
data = data.map { |x| [x['key'], x['value']] }.to_h
# => {"Name"=>"Jason", "Age"=>"21", "last_name"=>"bourne"}
```

The `#to_h` method expects each element of the array to be an array in the form `[key, value]`, so the `#map` call processes each element of `data` to convert it into that form.

Once this has been done, you can simply access keys like any other hash:

```rb
data['Name'] # => "Jason"
data['Age'] # => "21"
```

Answer (score 1):

The calculation should not depend on the keys of the hashes, in case they are changed.

```
data.map { |h| [h.values].to_h }
  #=> [{"Name"=>"Jason"}, {"Age"=>"21"}, {"last_name"=>"bourne"}]
```